# JS if / else if / not working correctly

Tags: jquery, if-statement, local-storage

I am having some difficulties in getting this work, and can't figure out what is causing the issue. Basically I am checking if local storage has item 3-step, if not create it and give it the value of 1. By having the value of 1 then add class "selected" to first LI, if the value is 2 then add class "selected" to second LI, and so on - this is happening on click of buttons and it is saving the values to the local storage correctly.

However when the page is refreshed and it does the check to see which li to add the class of "selected", it does not work. Only works if the value is 1, then it will add the class to the first LI, the other LIs will not work for some reason.

```js
 var ls;
 if( localStorage.getItem('3-step') == null ) {
    var ls = 1;
    localStorage.setItem('3-step', ls);
 } else {
    var ls = parseInt( localStorage.getItem('3-step') );
    if( ls == 1 ) {
       $('#li-one').addClass('selected');
    } else if ( ls == 2 ) {
       $('#li-two').addClass('selected');
    } else if ( ls == 3 ) {
       $('#li-three').addClass('selected');
    }
 }
```

```css
.selected {
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ul">
   <li id="li-one" class="section">
      Stuff One
   </li>

   <li id="li-two" class="section">
      Stuff Two
   </li>

   <li id="li-three" class="section">
      Stuff Three
   </li>
</ul>
```

But in the js script during the check to see what value is in the local storage, if I make the div id all to #li-one it works. Meaning if it's –– `if(ls == 3){ $('#li-one').addClass('selected')` –– this works, but if it's –– `if(ls == 3){ $('#li-two').addClass('selected')` OR `if(ls == 3){ $('#li-three').addClass('selected')` –– this does not work.

ALSO, I cannot get the example here to work at all – i guess localstorage is not allowed.

Thank you so much,

Sergio

Comment: You're not changing the value of `3-step` in `localStorage`

Comment: I am - as i mentioned - via button clicks. That part is working good.  I see the values change and they get saved with no issues. The issue is only when I refresh page I want it to add the class to the right LI with the corresponding ID.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and **the shortest code necessary** to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/tdj0e5pc/2/

```js
var ls;
 if( localStorage.getItem('3-step') == null ) {
    var ls = 1;
    localStorage.setItem('3-step', ls);
    $('#li-one').addClass('selected');
 } else {
    var ls = parseInt( localStorage.getItem('3-step') );
    if( ls == 1 ) {
       $('#li-one').addClass('selected');
    } else if ( ls == 2 ) {
       $('#li-two').addClass('selected');
    } else if ( ls == 3 ) {
       $('#li-three').addClass('selected');
    }
 }
 
 $('#ul').on('click', 'li', function(){
  localStorage.setItem('3-step', $(this).index() + 1);
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings('li').removeClass('selected');
 });
```

```css
.selected {
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ul">
   <li id="li-one" class="section">
      Stuff One
   </li>

   <li id="li-two" class="section">
      Stuff Two
   </li>

   <li id="li-three" class="section">
      Stuff Three
   </li>
</ul>
```

Check the solution in `jsfiddle` as the code snippet won't work.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes, your example works as I intend it to, but for some reason in my real code, the part that is checking the value in 3-step (in your js fiddle lines 8-14) it does not work. If I make the intended div all the first LI it works if I make the target LI the second or third, it will not work. really strange – I've done these things dozens of times and never had this issue.

Comment: Thanks Shiladitya, I have figured it out. The LIs are being generated dynamically and adding a set timeout creates a delay allowing the LIs to be generated and then runs the local storage check. That was my fault for not checking this initially. Thank you for your efforts.